# error using -libjars while running map reduce job

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run a map reduce job using hadoop jar command.
I am trying to include external libraries using the -libjars option.
The command that I am running currently is 
***hadoop jar mapR.jar com.ms.hadoop.poc.CsvParser -libjars google-gson.jar Test1.txt output***
But I am recieveing this as the output
***usage: [input] [output]***
Can anyone please help me out.
I have included the the exteranal libraries in my classpath as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you list the contents of your `main(String args[])` method? Are you using the ToolRunner interface to launch your job? The parsing of the -libjars argument is a function of the GenericOptionsParser, which is invoked for you via the ToolRunner utility class:

```
public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args)));
    }

    public int run(String args[]) {
        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

        // other job configuration

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```